# Passing Custom variables to password_change view in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to use the password_change view from contrib.auth.

So here is what I did:

1. Created a form that extended the PasswordChangeForm to add html classes to the widget
2. Created the registration/password_change.html template. Because you perform password change from a logged in state, this template must inherit from a base_site.html that displays the user a bunch of information (in addition to the form).
3. Updated my urls.py to create the pattern for URL, passing in the form name to the view.

Here is where I am stumped. The template, it renders content based on some custom variables. For example, the template has a custom tag that obtains information from the context.

```
business = context.get('business',None)
```

My question is: what are my options to passing domain specific context to the template? Should I go ahead and rewrite the password_change view (copy and paste) into my application view?

Answer (score 1):

Django's generic views emply an `extra_context` parameter for this purpose. However, auth provides its views as is; you don't have to use them.

Your only option is to simply recreate the view. You can copy the code from `password_change`, as a guide, but make sure you understand what it's doing before you just drop it in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that most reusable apps follow the design pattern of accepting extra_context and then merging the extra context into the context. However, the contrib.auth doesn't appear to follow that pattern.